# Dependent assemblies are only deployed when referenced by code

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, nuget-package

.NET Framework

I have a NuGet package with two assemblies. In my console app, I've referenced the package and can see both assemblies as references. In the console app's code, types from assembly one are used. Types from assembly two are only used via reflection. There is no 'static' reference to any types.

When I build the console app, it appears that assembly two is not copied into the output folder. If I modify the console app to statically reference types in assembly two, it is copied to the output folder.

Is there a way I can ensure assembly two is always copied to the output folder despite the absence of any static references to any of its types in the console app? The project `CopyLocal` setting is true for both referenced assemblies.

Comment: Framework or Core? How are you building it?

Comment: .NET Framework. Building via VS.

Comment: Are you restoring the NuGet packages before you build?